# Passing AND Changing a Variable in a Function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

This has got to be the most basic question. Maybe my brain is stuck in a Pascal and C myopia from the early 1990s tonight, but why does the value not get passed back below? If I remove the parameter altogether and change "str" to "name" inside the function (making it a global variable), then it works.

- Is it possible to do this, and if so, how do I do pass a variable like this?

What language syntax would I be confusing JS with here? Thanks in advance for the schooling. :)

```
var name = 'Jean-Luc';
  
function change(str) {
  str = 'Wesley';
}
  
change(name);
console.log(name); // returns Jean-Luc
                   // why is it not Wesley?
```

Comment: You *can* make C do that, or something like it, but usually you don't. C is also a pass-by-value language, as is Pascal. The only language I know (well the only common one) is FORTRAN that does that, and I have a suspicion that that was in the FORTRAN of 50+ years ago.

Comment: I do not see any JS relevant question here really, StackOverflow is for solving coding problems and not ask for which language youa re confusing some code behaviour you were expecting from your JS code with. Strings are immutable and basic datatypes in JS like numbers, so they are passed by value. JS does not know pointers really, only references, when passing object type variables and even then you can only change let's say the object's inner members and not the object itself. Like setting an object parameter to null would not affect the object given to the function as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

Using C/C++, you can change the value by passing address to the function or using reference inside the function.
But, you can't change the value by passing itself, though in C.
It is similar to Javascript.
If you send object, not variable, maybe you can change it. But not scalar variable.

```js
let g_name = { name: "Jean-Luc" };

function change(str) {
    str.name = "Wesley";
}

change(g_name);
console.log(g_name);
```